# Where is the geth.exe in the Ethereum mist?

Tags: mist, meteor

I'm running Ethereum Mist on Windows 7. Mist Version is 0.8.6.

I can't find the geth.exe in the Mist github.

https://github.com/ethereum/mist

In the version 0.8.2, the geth path was "`mist\nodes\geth\win32-x64\geth.exe`".

Anyone help me.

Comment: You could try `C:`, `cd \ ` and `dir /s geth.exe` to find it. It has been repackaged into a different directory recently.

Comment: so that, mist don't included geth.exe?

Comment: Mist is downloaded separately in the newer versions of Mist / Ethereum Wallet. See https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/58hoev/geth_path_is_changed_in_new_mist_ew/

Comment: Ok. thank you. @Bokky PooBah, your comment -> answer.

Comment: I've added the long answer so you can accept it if you are happy with the answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The recent version of Mist (and Ethereum Wallet) will download the appropriate version of `geth.exe` (Windows) or `geth` (Linux or OS/X) and save it into the `config` directory.

From [Mist Browser](https://github.com/ethereum/mist/blob/df2b54d098e16c1e91a813fa1baf6fd6173b105b/README.md#config-folder):

> NOTE: client-binaries (e.g. [geth](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum)) specified in [clientBinaries.json](https://github.com/ethereum/mist/blob/master/clientBinaries.json) will be checked during every startup and downloaded if out-of-date, binaries are stored in the [config folder](https://github.com/ethereum/mist/blob/df2b54d098e16c1e91a813fa1baf6fd6173b105b/README.md#config-folder).

From [Config folder](https://github.com/ethereum/mist/blob/df2b54d098e16c1e91a813fa1baf6fd6173b105b/README.md#config-folder):

> The data folder for Mist is stored in other places:
>
> Windows `%APPDATA%\Mist`
>
> macOS `~/Library/Application Support/Mist`
>
> Linux `~/.config/Mist`

In Windows, you will find `geth.exe` in a path like `C:\Users\{Username}\AppData\Roaming\Mist\binaries\Geth\unpacked`.

Answer (score 1):

Mist includes geth (you may have a PATH problem).
check :  https://github.com/ethereum/mist/releases

> This Wallet/Mist version contains the Geth 1.4.18 "Note 7", which
>   includes the EIP150 1b/1c Hardfork.

**Solution**

But to make it easier : download and install geth from : https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/releases
add the location where you uzip it to the PATH. Afterward, run geth with your parameters and then run mist, it will detect your running geth instance.